# Which markup language uses "====="?

Tags: markup

i need to understand the following configuration file on github -> https://github.com/GENIVI/vsomeip/blob/master/documentation/vsomeipUserGuide

Unfortunately it is written in a markup language i do not know and can't seem to find elsewhere. Can you tell me which one it is?

Comment: Might be AsciiDoc: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#section-titles

Comment: (Note: Those kind of questions are generally considered [off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345129/lets-stop-language-identification) here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like documentation rather than configuration, written in AsciiDoc.

In fact the `Build Instructions` section tells you what you need:

> - To build the documentation asciidoc, source-highlight, doxygen and graphviz is needed:

Answer (score 0):

As identified by Gereon, it is AsciiDoc. You can export this file into PDF, HTML and other format.s

If you're using VS Code, Ctrl + SHFT + P (or open Extension Marketplace) and type **AsciiDoc**. Install the extension. Open the AsciiDoc file, press Ctrl + SHFT + P and type AsciiDoc: Export document as pdf

The opened document will be exported as pdf. It might ask you download another package. Just let it do.